# Given a node set, enumerate graphs on it

Tags: python, algorithm, networkx, graph-theory, combinatorics

I have a node set

> N=[1,2,....n]

I can define 2^(nC2) graphs on this node set. I want to enumerate each of them in nondecreasing order with respect to the number of edges. Is there an efficient way to do it in python networkx? Assume undirected graphs, and by enumerating graphs i basically mean enumerating the adjacency matrices.

Comment: Are you sure this is what you want to do?   I can imagine this being vaguely possible up to n=7.  At n=8 you've got hundreds of millions of graphs to enumerate.    At  n=9 you're getting close to 100 billion graphs.

Comment: i just want to do it upto n=4,5 to test an idea related to a set of graphs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved using the below code. Basically, we use itertools to generate lists representing all possible graphs, sort them by how many edges they contain, generate a dictionary of lists representing that graph, and then return a list of networkx graphs corresponding to those dicts of lists.

**Code:**

```
from math import factorial as f
import networkx as nx
import itertools

def nCr(n,r):
    return f(n) // f(r) // f(n-r)

def get_all_graphs(n):
    rows = sorted(itertools.product(range(2), repeat=nCr(n,2)), key= lambda x: sum(x))

    indices = [sum(range(n-1, n-i-1, -1)) for i in range(n)] + [sum(range(n))]

    graphs = [{node: [j+node+1 for j, edge in enumerate(row[indices[node] : indices[node+1]]) if edge == 1] for node in range(n)} for row in rows]

    return [nx.from_dict_of_lists(x) for x in graphs]
```

**Example:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=4)

graphs = get_all_graphs(3)

for i, row in enumerate(ax):
    for j, col in enumerate(row):

        nx.draw(graphs[i*4+j], with_labels=True, ax=col)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

**Output:**

[image]

Or with the above example adapted for n=4:

[image]

Comment: thx 4 ans. could you describe in English what logic you used here: `[j+node+1 for j, n in enumerate(row[indices[node] : indices[node+1]]) if n == 1]`

Comment: Imagine that we have an adjacency matrix representing each graph. The members of the rows list are equivalent to the upper triangular part of that matrix, flattened into a 1D list. We split that list up into the chunks that it is comprised of if it were written in 2D form; so node 0 has n-1 possible edges, node 1 has n-2 possible edges and so on. That’s what the indices list does. Finally, if the element at that index is a 1, we want to create an edge to that point, otherwise we ignore it. Hope that makes sense, I know the code as written is rather esoteric.

Comment: Side note: we only need the upper triangular part of the adjacency matrix as we are dealing with undirected graphs, so the matrix is symmetric, and the diagonal is always 0 as we don’t want any nodes connected to themselves.

Comment: thx it helps. but there is one confusion you have used `n` as number nodes which is a constant parameter to the function `get_all_graphs`. but then `n` is again being used in the function as a variable. could you plz correct the names appropriately because the n's are confusing?

Comment: @user_1_1_1 ah I see, my mistake, yes I can fix that.